# Difference between using/not using parameter in function?

Tags: python

The code below determines if a number is prime or not.

I get the same outputs if I do `def prime(number)` as I would `def prime()` and for the if statement at the bottom. What is the difference between using the two?

```
def prime(number):
    if number > 0:
        for i in range(2, number):
            if number % i == 0:
                return False
            return True

number = int(input('Enter your number:\n'))

if prime(number):
    print('Prime Number!')
else:
    print('Not Prime Number!')
```

Comment: The answer has to do with [variable scope](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html#variable-scope-and-lifetime).

Comment: It's better to use the version with the parameter, because then you're not relying on a global variable.

Comment: Put your top-level code in a `main()` method (generally a good practice for many reasons). Then repeat your experiment where you try to call `prime()` without any arguments. You'll get an instructive error.

Comment: Not just variable scope, but the fact that there isn't another thread running that could change the value of `number` while `prime` is running.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this works is because if a variable is not defined in the local scope, then Python will get the global scope variable instead (if you want to alter a global variable from a local scope you should specify that with the statement `global my_variable`). Your names between these scopes should be unique such as:

```
def prime(local_number): # whatever is fed to our function we'll call "local_number"
    if local_number > 0:
        for i in range(2, local_number):
            if local_number % i == 0:
                return False
            return True

number = int(input('Enter your number:\n')) # our global variable

if prime(number):
    print('Prime Number!')
else:
    print('Not Prime Number!')
```

This is better practice, and now `prime()` will have an error while `prime(number)` will work correctly.